# C# web API POST JSON data using POSTMAN client results in always NULL in FromBody

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, http-post, postman

I am having a Web Api containing Model -

```
 public class Assessments
{
    public List<AssessmentResult> Results { get; set; }
}

public class AssessmentResult
{
    public int? AssessorId { get; set; }
    public int? AssessmentId { get; set; }
    public int? CentreId { get; set; }
    public int? BatchId { get; set; }
    public DateTime AssessmentDate { get; set; }
```

And Controller -

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("SetAssessmentResults")]
    public HttpResponseMessage SetAssessmentResults([FromBody] Assessments assessments)
    {
        try
        {

            string sproc = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ASSESSORAPP_InsertAssessmentsStaging"];
            //_dt = Helper.ToDataTable(assessments); use this if sending list doesnt work

            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                //cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = false;
                cfg.CreateMap<AssessmentResult, AssessmentTable>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();

                //cfg.IgnoreUnmapped();
            });
            List<AssessmentTable> assessmentTable = Mapper.Map<List<AssessmentResult>, List<AssessmentTable>>(assessments.Results);
            Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            string isSuccess = _db.InsertAssessmentResults(sproc, assessmentTable);
            if (isSuccess.Split('$')[0].ToLower() == "success")
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, isSuccess);
            }
            else if (isSuccess.Split('$')[0].ToLower() == "duplicate")
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, isSuccess);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, isSuccess);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }
    }
```

Client side, I am using Postman Chrome extension.
I am sending POST request with JSON data in body. However, I am not getting the JSON data in controller *(assessments object always shows NULL value)*

[assessments object showing NULL value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIOH2.jpg)

In client side, I am request using PostMan Chrome extension

[PostMan Client sending request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqz6U.jpg)

This is my JSON data :

```
    {
"assessment":
[{
      "AssessorId": 3,
      "AssessmentId": 123,
      "CentreId": 1,
      "BatchId": null,
      "AssessmentDate": "2016-09-30T00:00:00",

    },{
     "AssessorId": 2,
      "AssessmentId": 123,
      "CentreId": 1,
      "BatchId": null,
      "AssessmentDate": "2016-09-30T00:00:00",
    }]
    }
```

I have also added Content-Type : application/json

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you !

Comment: rename `"assessment"` to `"Results"` in your json

Comment: Make sure the name of your properties in JSON are identical to your C# model class.

Comment: It worked..... Thank you sooooo much :)

Answer (score 1):

In your class **Assessments** you name the property that contains the list of AssessmentResult "**Results**" but when you send the post you are naming the property "**assessment**" it should be "**Results**" **(considering you have the default serializer configuration eg: no propertie name to lower camel case when serializing)**

Try:

```
  {
     "Results":[{
                 "AssessorId": 3,
                 "AssessmentId": 123,
                 "CentreId": 1,
                 "BatchId": null,
                 "AssessmentDate": "2016-09-30T00:00:00",

               },
               {
                 "AssessorId": 2,
                 "AssessmentId": 123,
                 "CentreId": 1,
                 "BatchId": null,
                 "AssessmentDate": "2016-09-30T00:00:00",
               }]
 }
```

Also as a good practice you should instance the list in the constructor of your class
Eg:

```
public class Assessments
{
    public Assessments()
    {
         Results = new List<AssessmentResult>();
    }
    public List<AssessmentResult> Results { get; set; }
}
```